# Size of groups and generator set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups

> Let $F=\mathbb{Z}_2$ be a finite field with $2$ elements, and let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. $V$ is vector space over the field $F$ such that $\dim V=n$. We'll look at $V$ as a group with the $+$ operator.
>
> Let $S\subset V$ be a generator set of $V$ ($\left<S\right>=V$).
>
> Prove that  $|S| \ge \log_2|V|$.

Any ideas/hints?I'm not sure how to begin...

Comment: What is $G$? The same as $V$, but as a group?

Comment: @amrsa Sorry,this was a typing mistake,thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226412/s-geq-log-2v-for-generating-subset-of-vector-space-over-mathbbz-2

Comment: Won't that follow from $|V| = 2^n$?

Comment: @Crostul Why $2^{|S|} \ge 2^n \ge |V|$?

Comment: Are we to *guess* that $\;V\;$ is a linear space **over the field** $\;\Bbb F_2\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\;V\;$ is a linear space over $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ , we have that

$$\dim_{\Bbb F_2}V=n\implies |V|=2^n$$

and thus, since $\;S\;$ is a generator set, we have that

$$|S|\ge n=\log_22^n=\log_2|V|$$

Comment: Why $|S|\ge n$?

Comment: @ChikChak Because **any** generating set in **any** finite dimensional vector space of dimension $\;n\;$  has **at least** $\;n\;$ elements = the number of elements in *any basis*. Remember that a basis in a vector space is a maximal linearly independent set = **minimal** generating set.